# Centering picture above button to different webpage

Tags: html, css

I want to center a logo above a button that leads to a different page with js. I got that working but I can't get the image above the button. 
https://jsfiddle.net/0bzagL6x/2/ I am not good with html and css. It is my first project.

```
      <a class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectForum()">
      <img class="forum" src="img/forum.png" />
        Forum
      </a>
```

Thanks a lot!

Tom

Comment: `display:block` on image?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the images in each block to render above the "Forum" text, in this case, I would suggest usage of line breaks (`<br>`)

For example:

```
      <a class="btn" onclick="WebsiteRedirectForum()">
          <img class="forum" src="img/forum.png" /><br>
        Forum
      </a>
```

I hope this helps. Please comment if this does not answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could achieve this button layout using HTML and CSS.

The first thing I would do update the HTML markup and add a `<span>` tag around the button text - in this case, the word "Forum". This will allow us to select the text in CSS.

[Heres a codepen with two solutions](https://codepen.io/LukeBailey/pen/yqXOmm)

The first is a simple solution using `display: block` and `text-align: center`.
The second uses flexbox and is slightly more complicated (and probably overkill).

If you're starting out I would recommend [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn) as a good place to start learning HTML and CSS.